# Temporary failure in name resolution - Debian Book worm on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, static-ip-address

Recently tried to assign static IP with wireless to my Raspberry pi with Debian Book worm OS. After configuring interfaces file with static IP, IP is showing as assigned with the hostname -I command. But the Pi is not available on the network and getting temporary failure in name resolution when trying to ping other servers or router.

Tried adding the name servers in resolve.conf file too. Getting same error. With the DHCP assigned IP everything works fine. What might be causing the issue with static IP?

Comment: Not a programming question. Try [raspberrypi.se] or [unix.se]